# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined, bcrypt.hash()

Tags: node.js, promise, mocha.js, bcrypt

I'm trying to create a test user in the `before` block of my mocha test for which I need to hash a password. [Apparently you don't need a done() function if you use promises](http://tobyho.com/2015/12/16/mocha-with-promises/). I'm implementing bcrypt.hash just like it says in the bcrypt docs:

```
before(function(){
    //create a user and populate user's first recipes

    //create a User object
    return bcrypt.hash('newt', 10).then(function(err,hash){
        //create the user object
        var user = new User({email:'test@test.io',username:'test',password:hash})
        //save that user
        user.save()
    })
})
```

However, when I run the test it gives me an error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

What gives? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like your `bcrypt` has no function called `hash`.

Comment: Could you show your `before` hook completely?

Comment: bcrypt.hash() definitely exists, and in fact if I remove the promise and put the .then() function as a simple callback function it works fine. It's just when I add the .then() that it breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bcrypt.hash('newt', 10) is not returning a promise.

Make sure you are on the latest version of bcrypt and mocha as early versions of these packages did not support promises.  Also you could try reinstalling the modules.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm still a bit confused though. I've been using promises in node.js throughout the project without needing to require any sort of external library, and according to the bcrypt docs bcrypt promise support is native now, isn't it? Why isn't it the same here?

Comment: It probably has something to do with the mocha environment not necessarily with node.  I will try to test it locally real quick to check.  I'm guessing Promise is not defined in the mocha environment.

Comment: hmm I just tested it with bluebird and it's giving me the same error...

Comment: Also I just double checked and mocha should have native promise support, too.

Comment: hmm, yeah I just checked it locally and I was able to run bcrypt and it did return a promise.  I would make sure that bcrypt and mocha are upgraded to the latest versions.

Comment: Are you saying that my code above runs without bluebird or equivalent, then? The mystery deepens.... mocha and bcrypt are both updated... just checked the versions.

Comment: Yes your code runs just fine.  Locally I have it running.  No bluebird needed. Maybe try to remove your npm folder and reinstall if that doesn't work.

Comment: never mind, I uninstalled and reinstalled bcrypt and it works now. Time to flip some tables, but at least it works now. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I don't think I can accept the answer you gave in good faith, since it's not actually correct, but I'm happy to accept it if you want to write an answer basically just saying what we found, uninstall and reinstall bcrypt.

Comment: I did an edit, but I don't really care about the points.  Just trying to help people.

Comment: Also, i'm not sure why your using mocha, but I would use ava instead if your just starting a project.  Multithreaded test are significantly faster than single threaded test.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ava